LogisticRegression not returning correct results
I am trying to predict a classification using logistic regression, based on training data, for a series of points in testing data.
I am getting an output, without errors, but the results, I am told, are wrong (the incorrect output would be considered an error, but there are no errors when running the code).
The training data is a collection of 4 different categories in 375 points, there are 3 variates per point, so plotting on a 3D graph. I ran a counting program on the set and found that over 50% of the points are in classification 2. My initial results were all testing points came up as class 2. I have tried sorting the training data into several different sets: random selection of 125 entries (which is the size of the testing data), and finding the min number of all the categories, and creating a training set using the same number of points from each category.
No sorting = all class 2
random sorting = all class 2
equal class number sorting = gives me an answer that has points classified in all 4 categories, but when I plug them into the online final test form, I have an accuracy score of 26%, which is the same as random chance. So, I am not processing data correctly, and I am not sure where. I am hoping someone with more experience with regression classification can point me in the right direction.
Do I need to reformat (transform) the train_X, train_y, and test_X arrays before I call LogisticRegression? If so, how? Maybe I am just feeding it malformed data?
# forming tables to push through logistic regression
train_X = []
train_y = []
for i in range(len(train_table)):
    train_X.append(
        [train_table.x.iloc[i], train_table.y.iloc[i], train_table.z.iloc[i]]
    )
    train_y.append(train_table.label.iloc[i])

test_X = []
for k in range(len(test_table)):
    test_X.append([test_table.x.iloc[k], test_table.y.iloc[k], test_table.z.iloc[k]])

# Trying with and without normalize
clf = LogisticRegression().fit(normalize(train_X), train_y)
# clf = LogisticRegression().fit(train_X, train_y)

predict = clf.predict(test_X[:])
prob = clf.predict_proba(test_X[:])

results = pd.DataFrame(
    sort_results(test_table, predict, prob),
    columns=["", "timestamp", "UTC time", "label", "accuracy"],
)


Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a minimal reproducible example.

Welcome to SO. Please do not edit your question with "solved" etc to include the solution; post a self-answer in the answer space instead: https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer

So, I wrote a process that compared LogisticRegression and RandomForestClassifier and pushed my data through it. The accuracy was much better using RandomForestClassifier.
Turns out the LogisticRegression returning all twos was not an error, it was just results with low accuracy. I rewrote the program using RandomForestClassifier, and added RandomizedSearchCV which creates multiple trees, chooses the tree with the highest accuracy, and uses it to predict classifications.
The new returned values were still mostly 2's, but the accuracy was greatly increased.
param_dist = {'n_estimators': randint(100, 375),
              'max_depth': randint(5, 20)}

rf = RandomForestClassifier()

rand_search = RandomizedSearchCV(rf, param_distributions = param_dist, n_iter=10, cv=5)

rand_search.fit(X, y)

best_rf = rand_search.best_estimator_

print('Best hyperparameters:',  rand_search.best_params_)

predictions = pd.Series(best_rf.predict(to_pred_covariates))

